# Application or User Defined Error

Tags: excel, dictionary, vba

I have the following code in one of my workbooks. Basically, there are two sheets - one with a matrix where the top row is names, and the left column is dates. As of now, there are 735 rows (or dates) in the "attendance" spreadsheet, and around 80 names of individuals. It's supposed to track peoples' attendance.

I need to find out how much each person works per week. The code below attempts to do the following:

1. For each individual, scan the first period of 7 days (or 7 rows). Sum up that period, and place the value in a dictionary at an incremeneted item. So for instance, in 700 days, there will be a dictionary 100 units large. Do this only if the value which is going to be added to the dictionary is greater than 0 (if they worked that week)
2. Take this dictionary, and sum up the value of all the items in the dictionary, then divide it by the count of that dictionary, to get an average work week during a 7 day block.
3. Then, place the value of that dictionary into another dictionary, where the individuals name (top row in attendance sheet) is the key, and the value of the previous dictionary is the item.
4. In the "Summary Sheet", place  the item associated with each key in the 9th column. For instance -

Individual  |  Weekly Hours
John              |        20
Jane           |    15
Joe          |    12

the hope is to be able to derive the amount of work each person puts in per week unit (not 7 unit block) directly from attendance data that is entered into the spreadsheet.

The error occurs at the following line:

```
 For k = 2 To attendanceSheet.Range("a1").End(xlRight).Row
```

Excel says "Application or user defined error: #1004"

Also, any assistance with optimization would be appreciated as this seems to be rather bulky code.

```
  Public Sub calculateAverageWeek()

    Dim i As Long

    Dim attendanceSheet As Worksheet
    Set attendanceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Attendance")

    'calculate week block
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = attendanceSheet.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row

    Dim indivName As Dictionary
    Set indivName = New Dictionary

    Dim k As Long
    For k = 2 To attendanceSheet.Range("a1").End(xlRight).Row
            Dim total As Long
            Dim v As Variant
            Dim totalWeeklyHours As Dictionary
            Set totalWeeklyHours = New Dictionary
            Dim j As Long
            j = 1
            Dim curTotal As Double
            curTotal = 0

        'scan attendance worksheet
        For i = 2 To lastRow

            curTotal = curTotal + attendanceSheet.Cells(i, 2)
            If (i - 1) Mod 7 = 0 Then
                If curTotal > 0 Then
                    totalWeeklyHours.Add j, curTotal
                    j = j + 1
                    curTotal = 0
                Else
                End If
            End If

            If i = lastRow Then
                For Each v In totalWeeklyHours
                    total = total + totalWeeklyHours.Item(v)
                Next
               ' Worksheets("Summary").Cells(2, 9) = CLng(total / totalWeeklyHours.Count)
               indivName.Add attendanceSheet.Cells(k, 1), attendanceSheet.Cells(k, CLng(total / totalWeeklyHours.Count))
            End If
        Next i
    Next k

    For i = 2 To Worksheets("Summary").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
        Worksheets("Summary").Cells(i, 9) = indivName.Item(Cells(i, 1))

    Next i



End Sub
```

Comment: I can't see immediately why you would get an error on that line, but `For k = 2 To attendanceSheet.Range("a1").End(xlRight).Row` is equivalent to `For k = 2 To 1`, which is a bit pointless.

Comment: Should be `xlToRight`

Comment: @JNevill - DOH!!

Comment: @YowE3K I `xlToRight` should be sound here as it will stop wherever the data stops to the right of `A1`. I think you are like me and are getting your directions backwards (I have to hold up my hands to find the "L" to get it correct)

Comment: @JNevill - Wherever it stops on row 1, the `Row` will be `1`.  I'm just trying to work out whether the OP intends `k` to refer to a row or a column, and getting hopelessly confused by the code.  (P.S.  I also use my hands to work out L from not-L!! Learnt that trick when I was very young and still haven't forgotten it [although I have forgotten just about everything else])

Comment: OH! YES YOU are right. Sneaky ROW() at the end there. @bdpolinsky, I'm almost certain that you want here is `For k = 2 To attendanceSheet.Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Column` changing that to `xlToRight` and `.Column`

Comment: @JNevill - But the only time the code uses `k` is as a row reference, which is why I am confused.  (I might actually have to read the text of the question, and not just look at the code, before I will be able to work out what is intended :D )

Comment: It may help to see some data, as I also think it should be `For k = 2 to [...].Column`, but since `k` is later used as a row (`...indivName.Add attendanceSheet.Cells(k,1)...`, perhaps there's a value in that last cell in row 1 that OP wants to use?  @bdpolinsky, what do you intend `k` to do?  Also, are you *sure* that `CLng(total / totalWeeklyHours.Count)` will return a whole number that you will then use as a column reference?